# How to find the orthocentre in an argand plane of any triangle?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

If P($e^{i\theta1}$), Q($e^{i\theta2}$), R($e^{i\theta3}$) be the vertices of a triangle PQR in the argand plane, then the orthocentre is?

Comment: Is is $Q(i \theta_2)$ or $Q(e^{i\theta_2})$ ? Same question for $R$. Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write math formulas.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience @Gribouillis

Answer (score 5):

$P,Q,R$ lie on the unit circle and hence origin is the circumcenter. The centroid is easily found as $\dfrac{p+q+r}{3}$. Using the Euler Line theorem that centroid divides the lie joining orthocenter and circumcenter in the ratio $2:1$ we get the orthocenter as $p+q+r$

Answer (score 1):

Let $O$ and $H$ be the circumcenter and orthocenter of the triangle.

Since $H$ is the orthocenter, $PH \perp QR$. This is equivalent to $PH \parallel OM$ where $M$ is the mid-point of $QR$. 
In language of complex numbers, this becomes $H-P = \lambda_P(Q+R)$ for some real number $\lambda_P$. Same thing happens to the other two vertices.

The problem reduces to finding a complex number $H$ such that 
the $\lambda_P, \lambda_Q, \lambda_R$ below are all real numbers:
$$H - P = \lambda_P(Q+R),\quad H - Q = \lambda_Q(R+P),\quad H - R = \lambda_R(P+Q)$$

There is an obvious solution for this! Namely,
$$H = P + Q + R$$

Comment: Very cool solution! Can this be adapted to triangles whose circumcenter is not the origin? I'm afraid we can't take $Q+R$ as the perpendicular bisector there.

Comment: @zxen-xi the generalization is if $G$ is the centroid, then $OH = 3OG$. look at wiki entries of [euler line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line)